# Terraform and certbot - How to temporarily open ports? Alternatives?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm deploying AWS infrastructure with terraform. It's almost entirely contained within a VPC, behind a VPN. The only exception is `certbot`, which needs a port open to the public internet in order to verify site ownership.

Before terraform, we were temporarily opening ports when we provisioned new EC2 instances, and when we needed to renew certificates. Here are the main steps:

1. Launch instance
2. Configure security group with an open port
3. Run certbot and configure SSL
4. Lock down security group to only allow traffic through the VPN

For renewing certs, the steps are:

1. Adjust the security group by opening a port
2. Run certbot renew
3. Lock down security group to only allow traffic through the VPN again

How would I do something similar in terraform?

Alternatively, is there some other preferred pattern for this kind of deployment?

(Before you ask, we've already reviewed and rejected the idea of certifying through AWS ACM, because we don't need or want load balancing or a public CDN in this stack.)

Comment: Have you looked into DNS validation?

Comment: hm. So we'd create an aws_route53_record with a dependency on the ec2 instance... That could work.

How would you pipe the certbot value back to terraform, so that the DNS record could be populated?

Comment: For DNS challenge, does certbot have to be run from the machine that will use the certs? I don't see any reason it would need to...

Comment: You can run it with local-exec though it's probably something that should be separated from Terraform as it requires to be run every few months not once. Personally I have a cron job running on the CI that uploads certs to S3 and the machines have a cron to sync them. You could fully automate it and make it independent if you use Lambdas though.